# Ionic app lags a lot on chrome and device

Tags: javascript, android, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

So i recently started using the ionic framework, when i tried out making an android app and running it in chrome for the first time it was fast and snappy. Then I added a button which takes you to another screen which has navigation bars and side menus and custom font on both screens, after doing that my app became slow as hell! now i cant even click the button to take me to the next screen. The app doesn't even make server calls. It runs decently fast in firefox however if i use ionic serve --lab the app still lags there. Also i added custom fonts which when i load on an actual android device shows when i first launch the app however it never shows again on the second launch. I attached the code for both screens.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane class="customBackground">
          <div class="harpee" style="font-family: Freehand521, sans-serif">Harpee</div>
          <div class="motto">
              <p>A Culture of Happiness and Hope</p>
          </div>
          <div class="logIn">
              <h1>Log In</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="logInForm">
              <div class="list list-inset">
                  <label class="item item-input">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
                  </label>
              </div>
              <div class="list list-inset formSpacing">
                  <label class="item item-input">
                      <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                  </label>
              </div>
              <a href="homeView.html">
                <button class="button button-positive customButton">
                  Sign In
                </button>
              </a>
              <div class="customText">
                  <p>Forgot your Password?</p>
                  <p>Sign Up</p>
              </div>
          </div>
    </ion-pane>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>` 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <!--Fonts-->
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
        <ion-side-menus>
            <ion-side-menu-content>
                <ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
                    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
                    </ion-nav-buttons>
                    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios7-search button button-clear" ng-click="#"></i>
                    </ion-nav-buttons>
                </ion-nav-bar>

                <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
                    <ion-tab icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
                        <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
                    </ion-tab>
                    <ion-tab icon="ion-compose" ui-sref="talk">
                        <ion-nav-view name="talk"></ion-nav-view>
                    </ion-tab>
                    <ion-tab icon="ion-social-reddit" ui-sref="hdi">
                        <ion-nav-view name="hdi"></ion-nav-view>
                    </ion-tab>
                    <ion-tab icon="ion-person" ui-sref="you">
                        <ion-nav-view name="you"></ion-nav-view>
                    </ion-tab>
                </ion-tabs>
          </ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-side-menu side="left">
              <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
                  <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>

              </header>
              <ion-content class="has-header">
                  <ion-list>
                      <ion-item class="item item-avatar">
                          <img src="img/3.jpg">
                          <h2>User Name</h2>
                          <p>Brief Bio</p>
                          <!--This is the actual code to be used, to fetch user data and display as in the above code-->
                          <!--<img ng-src="{{item.img}}">-->
                          <!--<h2>{{item.title}}</h2>-->
                          <!--<p>{{item.description}}</p>-->
                      </ion-item>
                      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="#">
                          <i class="icon ion-person" ng-click="#">
                              My Profile
                          </i>
                      </ion-item>
                      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="#">
                          <i class="icon ion-person-stalker" ng-click="#">
                              Forums
                          </i>
                          <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
                      </ion-item>
                      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="#">
                          <i class="icon ion-loop" ng-click="#">
                              Connect
                          </i>
                      </ion-item>
                      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="#">
                          <i class="icon ion-gear-a" ng-click="#">
                              Settings
                          </i>
                      </ion-item>
                      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="#">
                          <i class="icon ion-power" ng-click="#">
                              Log Out
                          </i>
                      </ion-item>
                  </ion-list>
              </ion-content>
          </ion-side-menu>
        </ion-side-menus>
    </ion-pane>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
        <ion-view title="Home">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <div class="list card">

                    <div class="item item-avatar">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg">
                        <h2>Raphael Rigwanzo</h2>
                        <p>January 30, 2015</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item item-body">
                        <img class="full-image" src="img/3.jpg">
                        <p>
                            Exciting bootcamp happening in school. Alot of interesting lads here!!
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
                            <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
                        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                            <i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i>
                            Like
                        </a>
                        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                            <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i>
                            Comment
                        </a>
                        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                            <i class="icon ion-share"></i>
                            Share
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="talk.html">
        <ion-view title="Talk">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <div class="list card">

                    <div class="item item-avatar">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg">
                        <h2>Raphael Rigwanzo</h2>
                        <p>Developer</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item item-body">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="What's on your mind...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
                        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                            <i class="icon ion-android-camera"></i>
                            Upload Photo
                        </a>
                        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                            <i class="icon ion-ios7-location"></i>
                            Tag location
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="button button-block button-positive">
                    Post
                </button>

            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="hdi.html">
        <ion-view title="HDI">
            <ion-content padding="true">
                <div class="list card">

                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <h2>Harpee</h2>
                        <p>HDI Mascot</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item item-body" style="text-align: center;">
                            <img src="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
                        <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                            <i class="icon ion-clipboard"></i>
                            Know Your HDI
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="you.html">
        <ion-view title="Profile">
            <ion-content>
                <div class="userStatsBackground">
                       <div class="profile">
                           <img class="profilePicture circle" src="img/3.jpg">
                           <h1>Raphael Rigwanzo</h1>
                           <p>Developer</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="userStatsFill">
                           <div class="row userStats">
                               <div class="col">Talks</div>
                               <div class="col">Followers</div>
                               <div class="col">Following</div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="row userStats">
                               <div class="col"><h3>300</h3></div>
                               <div class="col"><h3>1200</h3></div>
                               <div class="col"><h3>300</h3></div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                </div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: why are you loading the ionic scripts and cordova multiple times?

Comment: First of all, you have an extra ` character in the beginning and the end of your html tags. Remove them so your code can be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one `index.html` where you load your `js` and `css` files, not in every page. Also, you have weird reference for your files like `id="home.html"`. So, I assume that you get your page with an anchor by referencing its id. This is not the way ionic works. You should make use of the angular controllers in order to navigate and render your views. As far as your fonts, how do you load them? Are they loaded on Chrome, Firefox? These links might help for that.

https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/use-font-awesome-glyph-icons-ionicframework/
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-font-usage/4270/9

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how will I be able to link the js and CSS loaded in the index page to other html pages that might need them. About using ids to get to my pages, that's what I learnt from an ionic tutorial.

Comment: You will have to user angular's ui-router. Ionic comes with angularjs. Here is a simple demo of this. https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/using-ui-router-navigate-ionicframework/ . Check carefully how the views are actually rendered. It's on a separate file where you configure your routes and urls.

Comment: I've understood UI routing, controllers and service thanks...what about the .css and .js loaded in the index page? How will I be able to link the data loaded once in the index page to my other htm pages?